# package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, classpath

after i updated to **hibernate-validator 4.2.0.Final**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>       
</dependency>
```

when trying to build my application with maven using **mvn install**
i am getting the following error:

```
package org.hibernate.validator.constraints does not exist
cannot find symbol symbol  : class NotBlank
```

here's my **.classpath** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

although there's no errors in eclipse.
please advise.

Comment: Why should `.classpath` matter? Check your project POM, which will be used to run `mvn install`.

Comment: did you try to remove `<scope>runtime</scope>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have marked the dependency as a runtime dependency. So it's not used to compile the project. Change the scope to `compile`.